# How to show marker on map in phonegap in android?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

[image]I am developing a phonegap app for android in which i have to show map to show markers on it and when markers are clicked i want to show a balloon type small window on current marker having image and some details.

Answer (score 0):

try this full code for your requirment. there is full code for  create dynamic markers on map.

```
function initmap(){

function getoverlayer(imageurl,storename,distance){
    var s=   '<div id="content">'+
  '<div id="siteNotice">'+
  '</div>'+      
  '<div id="bodyContent">'+
  '<div class="map_text_container">'+
  '<div class="map_user_img">'+
  '<img src="'+imageurl+'">'+
  '</div>'+
  '<div class="map_text_div">'+
  '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="">'+storename+'</h3>'+
  '<h4 id="firstHeading" class="">'+distance+' miles </h4>'+
  '<div class="more1">'+
  '<a href="checkin.html" target="_parent" >'+
  'Check in</a> '+
  '</div>'+
  '<div class="more">'+
  '<a href="" onclick="more();" >'+
  'More</a> '+
  '</div>'+
  '</div>'+
  '</div>'+

  '</div>'+
  '</div>';
  return s;
  }


  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {


        //var picurl="http:\/\/sp1\/rippr.wcfservices\/ripprdata\/sellers\/388\/testseller1237899.jpg";
        //var a=picurl.replace('\\','');
        //alert(a);
        var picurl=storedata[i].storelogo;
        //alert(picurl);
        var storename=storedata[i].sellername;
        var lat=currentlocation.coords.latitude;
        var lon=currentlocation.coords.longitude;
        var distance=getDistanceFromLatLonInMile(lat, lon,storedata[i].latitude, storedata[i].longitude);
        //alert(picurl,distance);
        if(distance<=2){
            infowindow.setContent(getoverlayer(picurl,storename,distance));
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
        else{
            infowindow.setContent(getoverlayer(picurl,storename,distance));
            infowindow.open(map, marker);

        }
        //alert('marker id'+ marker.id);
        localStorage.setItem('markerid',marker.id);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps JavaScript API v3 runs in PhoneGap apps, which has many features but it runs kind of slow, because the API is designed for PC browsers, not mobile browsers.

Google provides Google Maps Android API v2, which runs faster and it is suitable for mobile apps.

[phonegap-googlemaps-plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/plugin.google.maps) plugin allows you to implement a Google Maps easily. So check it out!
[image]

Comment: thank you!! for your quick response. i m trying this..thankyou so much